# How to fill a hidden field in a Django form?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django ModelForm with a required hidden field (required means that the corresponding field in the model is null=True and blank=True). Where and how should I fill this field (after submitting the form by the user) so that it is possible to save this form? My first idea is to tamper with clean() in the form and do something like:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(SomeForm, self).clean()
    cleaned_data['hidden_field'] = value_i_want_to_be_here
    del self._errors['hidden_field']
    return cleaned_data
```

It works, but it doesn't seem to be the best way.

Comment: sure thats the right way ... why wouldnt it be?

Comment: More importantly, why have a required hidden field which isn't filled on the client side?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you can go about this by creating an instance of `form.save()` then put the value you want in the specified field of the newly created instance. Finally save the instance. Example below:

`def form(request):
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save()
        instance.your_hidden_field = value_i_want_to_be_here
        instance.save()`

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could do as you're doing OR you could:

- Override `save` in ModelForm -> alter the field there directly in the model. In this way, you should not include the field in the modelform -> use an `excludes =` attribute specifying such exclusion.
- Override `save` in the model class or, even better and more separate, use a `pre_save` signal to modify the value. You will also need to exclude the field in the form.

To override a modelform `save`:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    instance = super(YourModelFormClass, self).save(False)
    instance.your_hidden_field = a_value
    if commit:
        instance.save()
    return instance
```

Remember this is a method you must write in your custom model form class.

To override a model `save`:

```
def save(self, *a, **kwa):
    self.your_hidden_field = a_value
    super(YourModelClass, self).save(*a, **kwa)
```

To use a signal:

```
from django.core.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save, sender=YourModelClass)
def your_custom_signal_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    instance.your_hidden_field = a_value
```

Usually the third is recommended if the change has to be considered in the model class. If, on the other hand, the change is in the form, you could do what you're doing or use the first alternative I gave you.